# Output unexpected

Tags: c, macros

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX(a,b) ((a)>(b))?(a):(b)
int main()
{
    double a = 100 , b, c, e;
    int d = -1;    
    b = 336;
    c = -33.600000000000001;
    e = a + (MAX(b, abs(c)) * d);
    printf("max is %f", e);
    return 0;
}
```

Output of this program is 436 whereas logically it should be  -236 . Can anyone explain me why output of this program is varying.

Comment: Use `fabs` for floating point absolute value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a + (MAX(b, abs(c)) * d);
```

to

```
a + (MAX(b, abs(c)) )*d;
```

Comment: I want an explanation of this incorrect behaviour what I am doing wrong in this program .

Comment: @user1492793 not debugging it.  Use some extra temp vars to simplify your compound expression so you can see where it is 'going wrong' with either printf or your debugger,  (Debugging 101).

Answer (score 2):

After the macro substitution, `a + (MAX(b, abs(c)) * d)` becomes:

```
a + (((b) > (abs(c))) ? (b) : (abs(c)) * d)
```

Note that `*` has a higher precendence than `?:`, so the result is not what you expected.

The correct macro should be:

```
#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
//               ^                 ^
```

This is a lesson that you should avoid using macros when possible. Because it's hard to write correct function-like macros.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of logically wrong Macro Expansion:

`(MAX(b, abs(c)) * d)` => `(((b) > (abs(a))) ? (b) : (abs(a)) * d)`

Here, `(abs(a)) * d` is higher precedence than ternary operator. Hence `336` (`= b`, the ouput of `MAX` macro) is not multiplied by `-1`.

Also, as I commented, use `fabs()` for floating point absolute value. `abs()` is used for integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
a + (MAX(b, abs(c)) * d);
100 + (MAX(336, -33.6)*(-1))
100 + (((336)>abs(-33.6))?(336):abs(-33.6) * -1)  /* Assuming fabs 33.6, may be 0 or other value otherwise */
100 + ((336>33.6)?336:-33.6)
100 + 336
436
```

Comment: `abs(33.6)` = 33 and not 33.6

Answer (score 0):

```
d = -1;
b = 336;
c = -33.600000000000001;
e = a + (MAX(b, abs(c)) * d);
```

when the macro is evaluated it becomes

```
e = a + (((b)>( abs(c))) ? (b):( (abs(c) ) * d )
```

here (b) * d gets evaluated before the ternary operator, so after the ternary operator gives the answer 336, d has been multiplied already so it doesnt change to negative..